# PHP concatenation string in email

Tags: php, email

Having some problems with my automated email, I've tried to concatenate the variables but, It is returning a blank page rather than redirecting.

```
$to = "*******";
$subject = "New signup";
$message = "
Name:" . $row['first_name'] $row['surname'] . 
"Date of birth:" . $row['dob'] . 
"Address" . $row['house']  $row['street'] $row['town']  $row['postcode'] . 
"Application type:" . $name . 
"Price:" . $a . 
"Country of birth:" . $row['origin'] .
"Phone number:" . $row['number'] . 
"Email:" . $row['email'] . 
"";
$from = "*******";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
header('Location: payment.php?id='.$row['app_id']);
exit();
```

Any ideas? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your missing the concatenation operator between the variables - `$row['first_name'] $row['surname']` should be `$row['first_name'] . $row['surname']`. It's the same for the Address line, too.

Comment: It may be an idea to ensure that you have error reporting switched on.  That would be a much more efficient way of checking syntax than using stack overflow...

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the concatenation operator between **every** variable and string:

```
Name:" . $row['first_name'] . $row['surname'] . 
"Date of birth:" . $row['dob'] . 
"Address" . $row['house'] . $row['street'] . $row['town'] . $row['postcode'] .
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't do multiline concatenation/assignment like that. Use a [HEREDOC](http://php.net/heredoc). It's a FAR easier to maintain and read:

```
$message = <<<EOL
Name: {$row['first_name']} {$row['surname']}
Date of birth:  {$row['dob']}
etc...
EOL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the concatenation by using string interpolation:

```
$message = "
Name: {$row['first_name']} {$row['surname']} 
Date of birth: {$row['dob']} 
Address: {$row['house']}  {$row['street']} {$row['town']}  {$row['postcode']} 
Application type: $name
Price: $a
Country of birth: {$row['origin']}
Phone number: {$row['number']} 
Email: {$row['email']}";
```

Comment: What about the variables $name and $a do I just put them in raw?

Comment: Yeah, they will be interpolated. The braces are only necessary for `'string'` indices in arrays.